# How can i access wwwroot of other Project in .net core 3?

Tags: asp.net-core

I have 2 projects:

> 1st: Administrator_Part
>
> 2nd: Client_part

I have some photos in wwwroot of Administrator_Part project and my question is how can I access the wwwroot of Administrator_Part from Client_part project razor page?

Answer (score 1):

actually I find a way for solving my problem
just add code blow into your startup.cs

```cs
// Access wwwroot For Current Root Project
app.UseStaticFiles();

//Access wwwroot of External Project
app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions()
{
    FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(
        Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), @"./../Administrator_Part/wwwroot/uploadImage/resize")),
    RequestPath = new PathString("/MyImages")
 });
```

and any whare eg into razor page you can use it like this:

```xml
<img src="/MyImages/1.jpg" />
```

just change the path....!