# using wwwroot from other project in BlazorWebView

Tags: wpf, blazor, maui, wwwroot, blazor-hybrid

I'm trying to build an application using a Blazor Hybrid Webview, which can be run both from a .NET MAUI application as well as a WPF application. All Pages/Components/Routing etc. are located in a Razor class library (the GUI library). I can't get the wwwroot to the contained in the UI library however.

In both WPF and MAUI the BlazorView hostpage needs to be a static file, wwwroot\index.html, which has to be located inside the running application. I don't want to have to copy things like images and styles all the time. They need to be in the UI library.

I tried all methods of including the folder in the running project, like

```
 <ItemGroup>
        <Content Include="..\GUI.Blazor\wwwroot\**" CopyToOutputDirectory="Always"/>
    </ItemGroup>
```

And also by directly using the UIs index.html by creating the BlazorWebview like this

```
<BlazorWebView HostPage="../GUI.Blazor/wwwroot/index.html">
    </BlazorWebView>
```

But with no success, I keep getting an error saying the folder isn't found, or Blazor simply crashes

Comment: Not sure I follow what you're saying. Isn't wwwroot where the compiled version of your web stuff will be copied to?  Why aren't you referencing where the source is?

Comment: The wwwroot just contains an index.html which uses js to initiate Blazor, and some static files like fonts and images

Answer (score 1):

> I don't want to have to copy things like images and styles all the time.

It seems impossible.

If you create MAUI app project:

1.Add the Razor SDK, `Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Razor` to your project by editing its first line of the CSPROJ project file:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Razor">
```

2.Add the root Razor component for the app to the project.

3.Add your Razor components to project folders named Pages and Shared.

4.Add your static web assets to a project folder named wwwroot.

5.Add any optional _Imports.razor files to your project.

6.Add a BlazorWebView to a page in your .NET MAUI app, and point it to the root of the Blazor app:

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyBlazorApp"
             x:Class="MyBlazorApp.MainPage">

    <BlazorWebView HostPage="wwwroot/index.html">
        <BlazorWebView.RootComponents>
            <RootComponent Selector="app" ComponentType="{x:Type local:Main}" />
        </BlazorWebView.RootComponents>
    </BlazorWebView>
</ContentPage>
```

7.Modify the `CreateMauiApp` method of your `MauiProgram` class to register the `BlazorWebView` control for use in your app. To do this, on the `IServiceCollection` object, call the `AddMauiBlazorWebView` method to add component web view services to the services collection:

```
public static class MauiProgram
{
    public static MauiApp CreateMauiApp()
    {
        var builder = MauiApp.CreateBuilder();
        builder
            .UseMauiApp<App>()
            .ConfigureFonts(fonts =>
            {
                fonts.AddFont("OpenSans-Regular.ttf", "OpenSansRegular");
            });

        builder.Services.AddMauiBlazorWebView();
#if DEBUG
        builder.Services.AddMauiBlazorWebViewDeveloperTools();
#endif
        // Register any app services on the IServiceCollection object
        // e.g. builder.Services.AddSingleton<WeatherForecastService>();

        return builder.Build();
    }
}
```

Comment: Could have stopped after the first line

Comment: You mean that after add `<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Razor">` ?

Comment: No after 'It seems impossible'. I just want to use an external wwwroot. It surely must be possible. I did manage to contain the Main.razor in an external Razor library.

Comment: Well, you can refer to this case: [How can i access wwwroot of other Project in .net core 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59431174/how-can-i-access-wwwroot-of-other-project-in-net-core-3). Wish it can help you.